# Magento block output gives empty string

Tags: magento

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue where the output of my block is an empty string.

I traced it down to the point where I could see PHP statements being evaluated in the template file, but inside `toHtml()` of class `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`, `$html = $this->_toHtml();` assigns empty string to `$html`.

I dig it further, and found that inside `fetchView()`, `$html = ob_get_clean();` assigns empty string to it, even when the template was included above this line, and I could see it evaluating with the use of debugger.

From here I am clueless on how to debug this, may be I am missing something wrong in my module (I am a beginner in Magento).

Here is the concerned code from the module:

**app/code/local/AnattaDesign/AbandonedCarts/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <anattadesign_abandonedcarts>
                <class>AnattaDesign_AbandonedCarts_Block</class>
            </anattadesign_abandonedcarts>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <anattadesign_abandonedcarts>
                <file>layout.xml</file>
            </anattadesign_abandonedcarts>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/base/default/layout/layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_dashboard_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>anattadesign/abandonedcarts/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>anattadesign/abandonedcarts/zepto.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>anattadesign/abandonedcarts/adminhack.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_dashboard_index>
</layout>
```

**app/code/local/AnattaDesign/AbandonedCarts/controllers/WidgetController.php**

```
<?php

class AnattaDesign_AbandonedCarts_WidgetController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "index action of widget controller";
        die();
    }

    public function renderAction() {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock( 'anattadesign_abandonedcarts/widget', 'root' )->setTemplate( 'anattadesign/abandonedcarts/widget.phtml' )->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody( $html );
        die();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/AnattaDesign/AbandonedCarts/Block/Widget.php**

```
<?php

class AnattaDesign_AbandonedCarts_Block_Widget extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

}
```

I am running this by an admin controller and making the `renderAction()` fire.

Comment: @AlanStorm Its at `app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/anattadesign/abandonedcarts/widget.phtml`

Comment: — the adminhtml theme doesn't have the concept of a base template.  Put you templates in default/default.  Also, search out the "include" line in the template block class to see the files that each block is trying to include.

Comment: @AlanStorm I did that, and it was trying to pick up the template at that path only, so that's why I placed my template file over there. And the real path for include is correct, that's why the execution of the script enters inside my template.

Comment: Should this be $html() or $html in $this->getResponse()->setBody( $html() );

Comment: @R.S Oh yes, that should be a variable `$html` but my problem lies before we get there. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Do you have any <layout> <updates> in /local/AnattaDesign/AbandonedCarts/etc/config.xml?

Comment: @R.S Yes! Added that to the question.

Comment: @AlanStorm I see what you are saying but both template & layout file seems to be working when placed under base directory. I added some more code, can you take a look?

Comment: Can you double check all your other modules to make sure that they are not using <anattadesign_abandonedcarts> in any other (adminhtml) layout xml'<adminhtml><updates><layout><anattadesign_abandonedcarts>...'. (I spend all day yesterday trying to figure out a block not display issue)

Comment: @R.S I am pretty sure there isn't any other instance because I have only this module over a default magento install.

Comment: @R.S Can you share the zip file of your code? Like host it on your dropbox for me please? Or anything that works for you?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58332815/AnattaDesign.zip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19027/discussion-between-ashfame-and-r-s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the die() in method renderAction()

```
class AnattaDesign_AbandonedCarts_WidgetController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    ....

    public function renderAction() {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock( 'anattadesign_abandonedcarts/widget')
                ->setTemplate( 'coming.phtml' )
                ->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody( $html );
    }
}
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear, output is not performed in Magento's controller actions.  Instead, a controller action is responsible for setting the body on the response object (usually via the renderLayout method).  After the controller action finishes, other events have an opportunity to modify the response object.  Once that's happened, then Magento outputs the entire response body with a single statement.

Comment: @AlanStorm Understood! I am just clueless why `ob_get_clean()` returned empty string even after buffering the template output, and it still does, when I trace it with xdebug.

Comment: @ashframe too many factors to figure that out here.  Usually when that happens to me it's because I'm looking at the wrong block. Using var_debug and var_debug(get_class($this)); (or var_debug($this) with xDebug installed) can help ensure that is or is not the care

Comment: @AlanStorm Gotcha! Thanks for the heads up.